# Comparing 1.3.52 and 1.3.54 as strings and as numbers

Tags: javascript, comparison, string-comparison

I am wondering why the following works:

```
oldversion = "1.3.52";
newversion = "1.3.54";

if (newversion > oldversion) {
    console.log('test');
}
```

but this does not:

```
if (1.3.54 > 1.3.52) {
    console.log('test');
}
```

I know that the last example won't work because they are not actual numbers. But I am trying to find out what JavaScript is doing when it encounters a string with a number in it.

This is what I found on [W3Schools' *JavaScript Comparison and Logical Operators* page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp):

> When comparing a string with a number, JavaScript will convert the
>   string to a number when doing the comparison.

So how come it converts the string to a number and suddenly I am not getting an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number` anymore?

Comment: `1.3.54` this is not a number, simple as that. `1` is a number or `1.3` is a number but adding further dots is invalid.

Comment: I am stating in my post that I understand this. That does not explain why my other example is working though. That is what I want to find out.

Comment: It's just doing a string compare.. So using this for version checking would be wrong.

Comment: Yes it would probably be wrong, but it works though and I want to understand why it does.

Comment: Your quote in the question is talking about something like `if ("2" > 1)`, ie a string _and_ a number, and in your first example you're using two strings, so there is no change.

Comment: It doesn't work, it only work in this situation.  for example '1.3.52' > '1.12.10' would return true, and that's wrong.

Comment: "It works" for the strings you have tested. Try `1.23.5` vs `1.3.5`…

Comment: How is '1.3.52' > '1.12.10' wrong though when it's exactly what I expect to happen when it returns true since the first versioning number is higher than the second?

Comment: Last time I checked  12  was greater than 3  :)

Comment: @Keith OP is getting confused about lexicographic comparison the same way Javascript is… :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a function which iterates the segments.

```js
function checkVersion(a, b) {
    var aa = a.split('.').map(Number),
        bb = b.split('.').map(Number),
        i,
        r = 0,
        l = Math.max(aa.length, bb.length);

    for (i = 0; !r && i < l; i++) {
        r = (aa[i] || 0) - (bb[i] || 0);
    }
    return r;
}

var oldversion = "1.3.52",
    newversion = "1.3.54";

if (checkVersion(newversion, oldversion) > 0) {
    console.log('test');
}
```

Comment: Oh, I like the map(Number), never thought of that..  I'm going to modify mine now.. But credit too you.. :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it's actually doing a string compare and not trying to turn anything into numbers.

You can verify this by trying:

```
var a = "a";
var b = "b";
console.log(a>b) // gives false

var a = "a";
var b = "b";
console.log(b>a) // gives true
```

Comment: Also `"1.21" > "1.200"` only _looks_ correct (because .200 = .2 < .21) but if you take the whole numbers 200 is definitely greater than 21. Replace the dot with anything and it becomes apparent  `"1z21" > "1z200"` - it's not really checking numbers but each character.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, when you compare a number and a string, the string gets transformed into a number. However, if the string contains an invalid number, the result will be NaN. This is funny due to the fact that:

```
NaN > 15 === false
NaN < 15 === false
```

So:

```
"1.3.52" > 1.4 === false
"1.3.52" < 1.4 === false
```

Obviously (and as you said in your post), comparing 1.3.52 with 1.3.54 will throw an exception because they're not valid numbers.

*Why "1.3.52" is interpreted bigger than '1.12.10'?*

Strings are compared using Unicode code point order. For example, "Banana" comes before "cherry". "9" is bigger than "80", but because "80" comes before "9" in Unicode order. Thus, "1.3.52" is interpreted as bigger than '1.12.10'.

An easy way to find out order between strings and not getting tricked is using sort. For instance, `["1.3.52", "1.12.10", "1.11.0.0.0"].sort()`

Comment: Thanks that is pretty helpful using sort() to clear the fog and show me exactly what is happening. How does the unicode order work with the dots in between though? Does it add up all the unicode characters inside the string?

Comment: I don't think it adds them up in order to decide the order. The thing is, order of the character in the string is important. For instance "2" > "12" === true (first char matters). I think it treats the dots like another character. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hope somebody can clarify it this is really true, but thanks for the help. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

@Nina's solution should be the accepted answer, as it will be easier to understand I think.  But anyway..

```js
function versionGreaterEqual(newversion, oldversion) {
   var ov = oldversion.split('.').map(Number), //credit Nina :)
       nv = newversion.split('.').map(Number);
   return nv.reduce(function (a,b,i){
     return a+=b>=ov[i];
   },0)===nv.length;
}

console.log(versionGreaterEqual("1.3.54", "1.3.52")); //true
console.log(versionGreaterEqual("1.3.54", "1.13.52")); //false
```